# SSIS Check if dynamic text file exists: If yes then execute next step to import, If No then loop (keep checking) until file exists & import

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis

I have an SSIS package that will be going into automation. Everything works as it should. However for it to move to automation I need to have some kind of loop / task set up that will check if a text file exists. If it does then execute next task to import, if not then it needs to check about every minute until file is there. The files are saved out buy another group titled AgencyReturnFile_yyyymmdd.txt. The yyyymmdd is the current date & the folder these are saved in are saved out daily & kept for history.

I have some variables set up:
[Variables set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuMkA.jpg)

In the Loop Editor I have InitExpression @FileExists = 0
EvalExpression @FileExists == 0

In the Script Task Editor using VB2015 although can be C#
ReadOnlyVariables: User::FullPath
ReadWriteVariables: User::FileExists

Script:

```
    Public Sub Main()
Dim strFolderPathSource as String = CType(Dts.Variables("User::FullPath").Value,String)
Dim intNumberFilesFound As Integer = 0

Try 
Dim collFilesInFolder As IEnumerable = Directory.EnumerateFiles(strFolderPathSource, "User::FullPath", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
For Each currentFile As String In CollFilesInFolder
intNumberFilesFound = intNumberFilesFound + 1
Next
Catch e As Exception
Concole.WriteLine(e.Message)
End Try

If intNumberFilesFound > 0 Then
Dts.Variables("User::FileExists).Value = 1
Else
Dts.Variables("User::FileExists).Value = 0
End If
Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I don't see an explicit question in your post. Could you explicitly ask what you are in need of so that we know how to help you better?

Comment: I am looking for a loop and or script task that will check if a dynamically named file exists. If it does then execute task to load it, if not then I need a loop or something that will continually about every minute until file exists & then execute import task. How do I get the loop to check & recheck until file is there?